# Navigate routing dosen't works good when click button back. Nativescript

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I tried this router code

```
    const routes: Routes = [   {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'image', component: ImageComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent
          }
        ]  
      },
   { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
   { path: 'registeruser', component: RegisterUserComponent },  
   { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }, ];
```

In HomeComponent I have this code:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I write this code, because I want to close application when I click back button

And in AppComponent I have this code:

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

My problem is:

I click Logout function that is in SettingsComponent,and navigate in LoginFirstComponent, in this moment, when I click button back (mobile), this navigatein SettingsComponent and a second the application closed. I want to close my app whene I click button back. I think that this problem is in routing because in AppComponent I have    `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`

I'm waiting for some idea how to issue this.

Thank you

Comment: try with writing a code to disable browser back button for all cases --
window.history.go(-1)

Comment: You think that my code is correct? In which part I can try `window.history.go(-1) `

Answer (score 0):

you could show this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api
I hope you help. bye.

Comment: I can't understand this package?!